# How to get items value json

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting JSON from a api GET call. I am trying to get a value of a item which I think is a array. I am trying to console log the low price of the json.

I tried to cycle through it like a array like open.openDate.btcusd[5] and so on.

//JSON DATA FROM API

```
 btcusd":{  
   "high":"9206.36",
    "low":"8804.57",
     "volume":"1291.122483",
      "last":"8989.64",
       "bid":"8987.88",
        "ask":"8998.24"
```

//Call

```
  coin.getOpen()
  .then(data=>{
    coin.ui(data);
    });
```

//Function

```
      async getOpen(){
    const openres = await
     fetch(`https://api.lakebtc.com/api_v2/ticker`);

     const openBtc = await openres.json();
     return {
    openDate : openBtc
    }
   }
```

//New Function to console.log
    ui(open){

```
 console.log(open.openDate.btcusd); //I want the low value

 }
```

Comment: Could you update the example data structure and make it valid JavaScript? Since it is currently incomplete, answers will use an assumed version. People are more willing to answer question if they see the poster at least spend some time to format the question.

Answer (score 0):

do call this function like

```
async function getOpen(){
const openres = await fetch(`https://api.lakebtc.com/api_v2/ticker`);
const openBtc = await openres.json();
//  console.log(openBtc.btcusd.low);
 return {
  openDate : openBtc
 }
}

//  function call
getOpen()
 .then(res => console.log(res.openDate.btcusd.low))
 .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

Didnt completely get your requirement here, but the response here is an object not an array.
We can convert to array and print the low values for different entries like :

```js
 async function getOpen(){
    const openres = await fetch(`https://api.lakebtc.com/api_v2/ticker`);

     const openBtc = await openres.json();
     return {
    openDate : openBtc
    }
   };

getOpen().then(data=>{
  
   ui(data);
  
});

function ui(obj){  
var arr = Object.entries(obj.openDate);
  var lowValues = arr.map(d => console.log(d[0] + " value of low is " + d[1].low));     
}
```